# Odd Oracle + .net behaviour when comparing types

Tags: string, oracle

My workplace has a .net application supplied to us by a postal service, it connects to an oracle database running on the same machine and is responsible for registering, storing and printing shipping labels.

Seeing as the database host etc. is configurable we asked the company if the application could be used over the network (simply copying it over to another machine resulted in "literal does not match format string" errors), all we were told is "it isn't possible". Not wanting to take no for an answer I poked around the exe with reflector.

Together with Oracle's v$sqlarea view I pinpointed the errors to a few date comparison functions, but I have no idea why the application was working in the first place on the original machine.

The original application uses queries similar to

`SELECT * FROM shipping WHERE date = '2011/03/28' --error`

easily fixed with something like

`SELECT * FROM shipping WHERE to_char(date, 'yyyy/mm/dd') = '2011/03/28'`

Why does the original application work without throwing any errors? The incorrect query pops up in the v$sqlarea view when the application is used on the original host, if I copy the query and run it manually using anything else it throws the error, if I run the application on any other machine it throws the error too, is there some setting in Oracle that is modifying queries on the fly, but only for queries originating from the local machine, while storing the original query in v$sqlarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a regional settings difference between the two client machines, since formatting of dates will be dependent on the culture used to convert the date to a string in .NET, and unless the application specifies a culture, it will use the settings of the current logged on user running the application.  This is obviously a problem if the database engine is expecting them in a certain format.  This problem is less likely to arise with parametrized queries, where the date parameters are passed separate from the query and as a date datatype instead of a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with dates, you must avoid String.Format based query generation. Use parametrized selects and parameters to set those values.

```
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT * FROM shipping WHERE date = :dataParam", connection);
    var param = cmd.Parameters.Add("date", OracleDbType.Date);
    param.Value = DateTime.Now;
```

It worked, because the format was matching the datetime settings on the developer machine and on the target database.

In other words: the issue is connected to an incorrect date time format you are trying to provide.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of regional settings on the server. Please check that the new server is configured for the same Locale (EN-GB, EN-US, or whatever the original server is configured to use).